# dealing with complex data structre value

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, knn

I have two co-ordinate values. And I am calculatting euclidian distance for each co-ordinate. I want to apply K- nearest neighborhood algo here.

1. For each co-ordinate get euclidian distance with all other points
2. Select the point which is nearest to maximum points (from all points, select that point which appears as nearest for maximum numbers of co-ordinates)

   ```
       $result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT pcount, ncount from test");
       $result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT pcount, ncount from test");
       $i = 0;
                   $k = 0;
       $min = 0;
       while ($row1 = @mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
       {
           $pcount = $row1['pcount'];
           $ncount = $row1['ncount'];
           echo "pcount is $pcount<br/>";
           echo "ncount is $ncount<br/></br>";
           $a[$i] = $pcount ;
           $b[$i] = $pcount ;
           $j = 0;
           $result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT pcount, ncount from test");
           while ($row2 = @mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
           {
           //echo "j is $j <br/>";
           $a[$j] = $row2['pcount'];   
           $b[$j] = $row2['ncount'];
           $diff = ($a[$i] - $a[$j])^2 + ($b[$i] - $b[$j])^2;
           if( $diff != 0)
               $diff = sqrt( $diff );
               $j= $j + 1;
               echo "$diff <br>";
                           arr[$k] = $diff;
                           $k = $k + 1;
           }               
           //echo "i is $i <br/>";
               $i = $i + 1;    
       }
   ```

Here, `arr[$k]` contains distance difference for all points. 
How can I get point which is nearest to maximum other points here. There may be more then 1 such points.

Comment: Why you perform two identical db queries? `$result1` and `$result2` represents the same data. So you simply waste the memory. You have to perform one query, fetch it results in one array and use this array in loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use the following method.

**0)** Fetch db data into 2d array looks like this:

```
array(
    array($x1,$y1),
    array($x2,$y2),
    ...
)
```

**1)** Build array storing for each point sum of (square) distances to all other points.

**2)** Find the lowest value in that array (minimum).

**3)** Get all points having that value.

So the code should look like this:

```
// $a_points = array( array($x1,$y1), array($x2,$y2), ... ); // array of point coordinates

$a_sum_dists = array();
foreach ($a_points as $i => $pt1) {
    list($x1, $y1) = $pt1;
    $sum = 0;
    foreach ($a_points as $j => $pt2) {
        if ($j == $i) continue;
        list($x2, $y2) = $pt2;
        $sum += pow($x2- $x1, 2) + pow($y2- $y1, 2);
    }
    $a_sum_dists[$i] = $sum;
}
$min_sum = min($a_sum_dists);
$a_result_points = array_intersect_key(
    $a_points, 
    array_filter($a_sum_dists, function ($v) use ($min_sum) {
        return $v == $min_sum;
    })
);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/nCDYdh)

Comment: thanks a lot. I guess I will reach my goal now. But here there is mistake in logic.  We are getting some of all points in `$a_sum_dists[$i] `. But i think as per nearest neighborhood algo, it should find distance for each points and from them getting co-ordinates with minimum distance.

Comment: I don't quite understand your note. Where is mistake? My algo find point(s) which have the lowest total distance to all other points. Is it not what you want?

Comment: thanks but I want little different. What I want is: Suppose pint (x1,y1) has k neighbours, then from all k points find those cordinates which are on smallest distance. There may be more then one.  Now we have nearest point list of each cordinates. So now from this we need to find point which is appearing most frequently as nearest neighbor. The most dense point.

Comment: Your formulation of the problem is too vague. First of all, you shouldn't use "neighbour" term as it completely depends on distances between points. You cannot tell whether some point is neighbour to some other point until you calculate all possible distances.

Comment: actually name of the algo is nearest neighborhood algo. Your help was reasonable and appreciable, but I was not clear with my statements. My 2nd last comments seems clear. LEt me know if you have doubt in it. Or I will try myself and try to figure out.

Comment: IMHO you are confusing terms. Nearest neighbour algorithm is intended for application in problems of  optimal path search such as Travelling salesman problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem). Your problem, as it was given in the question, isn't related to such problems. You've asked algo to "find the point which is nearest to maximum points". I suppose that this point must comply with the following condition: total of distances from current point to all other points should be the lowest. Although this statement is intuitive. now I cannot provide proof for it.

Comment: Can we say it variation of KNN? My ultimate goal is to get point which is nearest to maximum other points. i.e. kinda most dense point

Comment: Your problem can't be a variation of K-NN. K-NN (k-Nearest Neighbors) is an algorithm, not a problem, and it is intended for problems much more complex than yours. Although it can be applied for your problem (in general), it's like to use a sledgehammer to crack a nut.